# How to handle PassportJS endpoint errors

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

If I visit the Facebook callback link at `http://localhost/login?code=***`

with a bogus code: `FacebookTokenError: Invalid verification code format.`
with the same code (replay attack): `FacebookTokenError: This authorization code has been used.`
with an expired code: `FacebookTokenError: This authorization code has expired.`

All of these errors are irrelevant to the client. I would like to simply retry the login process (redirect to Facebook again for authentication).

```
Express().get('/login', Passport().authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/',
}), function(req, res) {

});
```

However, upon error of those three described above, the server simply throws an error and emits to the client.

Is there an error callback for endpoint errors available?

Comment: Its HIGHLY debatable that the errors are "irrelevant to the client" – perhaps you mean they are irrelevant to your end user?

Comment: @jibsales Yes, the end user should not expect these error messages. (client = end user, in my dictionary :D)

Comment: Its unfortunate, but a quick stroll through the source code shows no error callbacks available. You can't simply redirect to Facebook because the end user must re-enter their credentials (part of how OAuth works)

Comment: You could, however, save the user's ID (not their password!!!) in local storage on the client (browser) and refill in the user ID field so you can save them a step.

Comment: There might not be any callbacks from passport-facebook, but I imagine there must be some customization from passport or even express. I just don't want someone to visit `/?code=random` and throwing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'm using:

```
// Google OAUTH sendoff
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google')
);

// Google OAUTH return
app.get('/auth/google/return', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('google', function(err, user, email) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    // OAUTH success, but user isn't authorized
    if (!user && email) {
      return res.redirect('/myNotAuthorizedUrl');
    // OAUTH error
    } else if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('/login/');
    // user disabled or some other check
    } else if (user.get('is_blacklisted') !== 1) {
      return res.redirect('/youAreEvil');
    }
    // success and authorized
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/home');
    });

  })(req, res, next);
});
```